# How to set security descriptor(DACL) for wifi profile with ACL contains only connect/disconnect access to WD(Everyone group)

Tags: c++, winapi, dacl

If a wifi profile is configured manually by entering password, non admin users can't see the password with netsh command, but when the profile is added via wlansetprofile anyone can view the password if security descriptor is not set. As an alternative I've tried wlanGetSecuritySettings() to get the default DACL of the wifi profile, but it is also failing with parameter is incorrect (87).

In c++ I'm using win32 api to set a wifi profile with security descriptor.

I've tried most of the combinations to deny read control alone and allow write control, but nothing is denying the read access and providing access to connect/disconnect at the same time.

I need to restrict the normal users from viewing the password of a wifi profile with netsh. So I'm trying to restrict read access for WD users and WD can connect or disconnect using the profile.
But using the below DACL users are able to view the password via CMD netsh command and if I deny access to RC I'm having issue with connecting the wifi.

```
hClient - handle returned from wlanOpenHandle().
WlanSetProfile(hClient,&(pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid),dwFlag,strProfileXmlW, L"O:WDG:WDD:(A;;CCWP;;;WD)(D;;RC;;;WD)",FALSE,NULL,pdwReasonCode);

Using WlanSetProfile function with "strAllUserProfileSecurity" parameter with the security descriptor string1 = "O:WDG:WDD:(A;;CCWP;;;WD)(D;;RC;;;WD)".
O:Owner - allusers
G:Group - allusers
A - access allowed
CC - create child
WP - write property
D - access denied
RC - read control
string2 = "O:WDG:WDD:(A;;CCWPRC;;;BA)(A;;CCWP;;;WD)(D;;RC;;;WD)"

WlanGetSecuritySettings(hClient, wlan_secure_add_new_all_user_profiles, NULL, NULL, &grantedAccess);
```

Comment: If a user has `WLAN_EXECUTE_ACCESS`, then the user also has `WLAN_READ_ACCESS`. As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't deny read access and provide connected/disconnected access at the same time.

Comment: But when a wifi profile is added manually by entering password, the password is only visible for admin users via netsh. I'm confused with this behavior.

Comment: According to the access mask of the object, as far as I'm concerned, you couldn't deny read access and provide connect/disconnect access at the same time through WinAPI.